# How to execute multiply queries using PHP's prepared statemens with MySQL's transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions, prepared-statement

I need to execute 2 or more not identical queries (`INSERT`'s in this example.) using PHP's prepared statements and MySQL's transactions. So if I have a 2 `INSERT` statements, I want both of them executed, or none of them.

I want to traslate this example MySQL transaction to a PHP code:

```
START TRANSACTION;
     INSERT INTO `file` (`name`, `mime_type`, `size`, `comment`) VALUES ('file.png', 'image/png', '1024', 'My comment');
     INSERT INTO `complementary_file` (`file_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '1');
COMMIT;
```

PHP code I'm working on:

```
mysqli_autocommit($connection, FALSE);
if ($stmtFile = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO `file` (`name`, `mime_type`, `size`, `comment`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtFile, 'ssis', $name, $mime_type, $size, $comment);
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtFile)) {
        if ($stmtComplementaryFile = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO `complementary_file` (`file_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtComplementaryFile, 'ii', mysqli_insert_id($connection), $user_id);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtComplementaryFile);
        }
    } else {
        mysqli_rollback($connection);
    }
}
mysqli_commit($connection);
```

PHP code above works but what if I have more critical statements to execute? Is there are good way to execute statements with PHP's prepared statemens *and* transactions at the same time?

Please note that for `$stmtComplementaryFile` I must have a `mysqli_insert_id()` value. Also please note that I am not using PDO with this code — I appreciate if suggestions will be MySQLi. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to run `mysqli_begin_transaction` before the prepares? (note: this isn't to answer your question, I'm just wondering because you're translating a transaction but not using a transaction in PHP).

Comment: I added `mysqli_begin_transaction($connection, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);` after `mysqli_autocommit($connection, FALSE);` and now both of `INSERT`'s doesn't work.

Comment: Well it wouldn't work when it's a read only transaction I guess.

Comment: Oops! Changed it to `MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE `, both `INSERT`s worked.

Comment: It looks like the code in the question has been edited to include an answer, and this question remains open, with no answer. If the answer to the original question was ... "add a call to mysqli_begin_transaction()", then that should be posted as an *answer* to the question, and the answer should be accepted. The way it stands now, it looks like the question is still unanswered.  (Bad form.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I originally thought this question was more of a "good practices" question and not a "how to implement transactions in PHP" so in that sense this question is probably still unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL:

```
START TRANSACTION;
     INSERT INTO `file` (`name`, `mime_type`, `size`, `comment`) VALUES ('file.png', 'image/png', '1024', 'My comment');
     INSERT INTO `complementary_file` (`file_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '1');
COMMIT;
```

Can be converted to PHP (with prepared statements) as follows:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($connection, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
if ($stmtFile = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO `file` (`name`, `mime_type`, `size`, `comment`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtFile, 'ssis', $name, $mime_type, $size, $comment);
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtFile)) {
        if ($stmtComplementaryFile = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO `complementary_file` (`file_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtComplementaryFile, 'ii', mysqli_insert_id($connection), $user_id);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtComplementaryFile);
        }
    } else {
        mysqli_rollback($connection);
    }
}
mysqli_commit($connection);
```

In general these two statements are equivalent, however it's a good idea to know what transactions are and what transactions are not.

Transactions are a mechanism to ensure that bulk operations are executed atomically and their results are reflected in the database only if ALL of them succeed. It ensures `atomicity` of operations.

Transactions are not a mechanism to implement a mutual exclusion lock on the tables. If a table needs to be locked then the `LOCK TABLES [READ|WRITE]` needs to be used. Equivalently in PHP this is achieved by doing a:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "LOCK TABLES tableName as TableAlias [read|write]");
```

followed by

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UNLOCK TABLES");
```